# Uniq an array by one column and join another column

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I need to convert this array:

```
[{a: 1, b: 1}, {a: 1, b: 2}, {a: 2, b: 5}]
```

into:

```
[{a: 1, b: "1, 2"}, {a: 2, b: 5}]
```

Any simple function?

Comment: Sorry, but could you elaborate the logic of the operation better? It's kinda confusing why you grouped the value of the second hash but not the last one

Comment: After a numerous operations, I will get an array that contain list of (repeated) users with same Id but different role field  
  
something like this  
users = [{id: 1, role: 'Admin'}, {id: 1, role: 'Editor'}, {id: 3, role: 'Moderator'}]

And I need to process this into  

[{id: 1, role: 'Admin, Editor'}, {id: 3, role: 'Moderator'}]

Comment: So your "a" value is the one for the users id and "b" value is the one for role field?

Comment: @RonanLopes Edited my comment. need more info?

Comment: For example, if you had [{a: 1, b: 1}, {a: 1, b: 2}, {a: 2, b: 5}, {a:2, b:6}], the output would be [{a: 1, b: "1, 2"}, {a: 2, b: "5,6"}] ?

Comment: @RonanLopes Thats correct, easy methods?

Comment: @shajin Please don't change the question (especially after an answer is given).

Comment: @sawa I did not see the answer while editing, but I edited your answer. Peer will review and the changes will be displayed

Comment: If these are values fetched by a database query you can get simular results in a much more effective way by applying a group clause to the query.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
[{a: 1, b: 1}, {a: 1, b: 2}, {a: 2, b: 5}]
.group_by{|h| h[:a]}
.map{|a, h| {a: a, b: h.map{|h| h[:b]}.join(", ")}}
# => [{:a=>1, :b=>"1, 2"}, {:a=>2, :b=>"5"}]
```